# Pandas using apply function to filter year and get mean value of months

Tags: python, pandas

in the following dataframe there are three columns year, month, vals. I am trying to filter out values for year, below a certain threshold (i.e 2007) and then obtain the mean vals for grouped months. (i.e month 9 has three values for respective years 2006,2001,2006 (less than year 2007), so the combined total (2.9 +8 + 9). I have tried multiple ways but something is quite not right. Right now the error I am getting is "Keu error 'year'" Any ideas what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2005,2006,2007,2005,2008,2006,2004,2007,2001,2006], 'month': 
[7,9,12,7,9,8,6,2,9,9], 'vals': [1.2,2.9,3.5,4.3,1.3,1.7,2.6,4.3,8.0,9.0]})
print(df2)

def mn(x,ylt):
if x['year'] < ylt:
    return x.mean()

df2.groupby('month')['vals'].apply(lambda x: mn(x,2007))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then aggregate `mean`:

```
df = df2.loc[df2['year'] < 2007, 'vals'].groupby(df2['month']).mean().reset_index()
#alternative
#df = df2.loc[df2['year'] < 2007].groupby('month')['vals'].mean().reset_index()
print (df)
   month      vals
0      6  2.600000
1      7  2.750000
2      8  1.700000
3      9  6.633333
```

If need all months, also non matched add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by all posible unique `months`:

```
df = (df2.loc[df2['year'] < 2007, 'vals']
        .groupby(df2['month'])
        .mean()
        .reindex(df['month'].unique())
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   month      vals
0      2       NaN
1      6  2.600000
2      7  2.750000
3      8  1.700000
4      9  6.633333
5     12       NaN
```

Your function should be changed with filtering, but unfortunately slow if many groups in large `DataFrame`:

```
def mn(x,ylt):
    return x.loc[x['year'] < ylt, 'vals'].mean()

df = df2.groupby('month').apply(lambda x: mn(x,2007)).reset_index(name='vals')
print (df)

   month      vals
0      2       NaN
1      6  2.600000
2      7  2.750000
3      8  1.700000
4      9  6.633333
5     12       NaN
```